# ¿Cómo seleccionar bloques hermanos (adyacentes) con CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, selectores-css

¿Cómo acceder a los hijos del padre de un elemento sólo con CSS?

Me refiero a que si tengo una estructura donde hay un padre que contiene un div y varios botones, el estilo de los botones depende del id del div.

Sólo lo he conseguido de una manera, Pero me gustaría saber si actualmente hay otras formas solo con CSS, porque con JavaScript se que es sencillo.
Este es mi ejemplo:

```css
#red-message ~ .button{
    color:red;
}

#blue-message ~ .button{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div id="red-message">Red Team</div>
    <button class="button">button1</button>
    <button class="button">button 2</button>
    <button class="button">button 3</button>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div id="blue-message">Blue Team</div>
    <button class="button">button1</button>
    <button class="button">button2</button>
    <button class="button">button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: La manera que has usado es la única disponible con **CSS** ya que no tenemos la posibilidad de acceder a ancestros o a hermanos anteriores, solamente a descendientes o hermanos posteriores.

Comment: Vale. al menos queda el código para los que requieran darle uso.

Comment: Ceo que la pregunta debiera ser  ¿cómo seleccionar bloques **hermanos** (adyacentes) con CSS?

Comment: puedes cambiar la estructura de tu html, meter los botones dentro de `blue-message` y seleccionarlos con el selector `#blue-message button`. Obviamente esto te puede servir si no se rompe tu layout

Comment: pues puedes utilizar last-child() para seleccionar ciertos elementos en los bloques adyacentes pero te tomaria mas lineas de stilos y no seria muy ordenado para el codigo en Css

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

Actualmente esa es la única forma de aplicar estilos a los hermanos de un elemento.

Si sólo quisieras aplicárselo al primer botón de cada grupo podrías con:

```css
#red-message + .button {
    color: red;
}

#blue-message + .button {
    color: blue;
}
```

Esto se aplica a los .button que vayan directamente detrás de #red-message o #blue-message.